# Implementation of an IObservable as a List

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# (and I still know just a little bit), and I need to implement a function in an exercise that will return an IObservable to a Test, I can't import System.reactive in this class, so I believe that I will need to implement the interface.

The tests will use this like `list.ToEnumerable().ToArray();`, and this variable list receives the return of my funcion that is marked as a `public IObservable<T> getList()`

How should I implement this Observable to return? Thanks!

**[edit]**

The major doubt is, what I should put inside my implementation of IObservable, that the test will get a list when he calls.ToEnumerable() from the return of this method getList()?

**[edit 2]**

That is my actual implementation of IObservable

```
public class MyObservable<T> : IObservable<T>, IDisposable
{
    private List<IObserver<T>> observers;
    private List<T> subject;

    public MyObservable()
    {
        observers = new List<IObserver<T>>();
        subject = new List<T>();
    }

    public void addPath(T path)
    {
        subject.Add(path);
        foreach (var observer in observers)
        {
            if (path != null)
                observer.OnNext(path);
            else
                observer.OnError(new Exception("Houve um erro com a solução"));
        }
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(observer);
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I have to implement this interface:

```
public interface IGraph<T>
{
    IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> getList(T source, T target);
}
```

This `IEnumerable<T>` is implemented and working to make the paths, but we return a list of paths, this list that is in an IObservable, the unit test use this in this way:

```
var paths = graph.getList(source, target);
var list = paths.ToEnumerable().ToArray(); //Here in Debug the execution doesn't move
```

With debugging I see that even without create any Observers, when execution reaches `paths.ToEnumerable().ToArray();` the Subscribe method in IObservable implementation is called

I'm not sure if i'm returning correctly, and why this call to Subscribe after getList() return the `IObservable<IEnumerable<T>>`to the test.

Comment: The documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iobservable-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2 (which has an example). Your question as it stands is too broad for StackOverflow. You should try something and come back if you get stuck!

Comment: Sorry about that, I tried this "first step" from many ways, but no one give a solution that the Test that I receive have accepted.

Comment: Please show what you have so we can see what's not working

Comment: Perhaps your `GetList()` method can just return the `private List<IObserver<T>> observers;`..?

Comment: Added actual code